# HtmlTextWriter.WriteAttribute is inserting html entity references where I don't want them

Tags: c#, html, htmltextwriter

For some reason the HtmlTextWriter is inserting weirdness into my html output.  In the following code I try to create a clickable div that contains an image:

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, "location.href = '" 
    + TargetHTTPRef + "'");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, ThumbFileName);
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);
writer.RenderEndTag();
```

I get the following output:

```
<div class="leftGallery" onclick="location.href = &#39;http://www.google.com&#39;">
<img src="./images/services/47_Kayak%20Thumb.jpg" /><div class="galleryPanel">
```

So I'm getting &#39 and %20 occurring where the apostrophes and spaces should be in the output.  Is there a way to stop this??

Answer (score 2):

Try another [`HtmlTextWriter.AddAttribute` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153285%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
writer.AddAttribute(
    HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick,
    "location.href = '" + TargetHTTPRef + "'",
    false);

writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, ThumbFileName, false);
```

The third argument to this overload indicates whether to encode the attribute and its value.

Comment: Seems to work for the apostrophes.  Does not work for the spaces however but I think that might be ok.